# Port 80 Blocked Despite Firewall Exception and Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, port

I am running a microscopic IIS installation on my Windows 8.1 Pro laptop with standard Port 80 and 443 (https), as a hobby.  Yesterday, while remotely managing the machine, port 80 suddenly and completely stopped working. I've tested Apache, also not working on port 80. I've double-checked and reconfigured my firewall, router, IIS setup, everything.  With all gates open to Port 80, [YouGetSignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) reports that port 80 on my public IP is closed.  443 (https) still works.  I can get to Port 80 *inside* my network, so I know it's not a machine issue.  My router forwards ALL OTHER ports correctly, so I don't think it's a router/modem issue.

There's nothing left to check; is Comcast blocking Port 80?  Their list of blocked ports does not include Port 80...

Comment: So just chnage the port IIS uses...

Comment: Comcast doesn't block port 80 so far as I know (it's not listed on their block list and they certainly don't block it in my area).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I never followed up on this; this was a dumb one.  Turned out my Netgear WNDR3400v3 Router **did** sabotage port 80 when I enabled remote management for the router (even though I set the RM port to 8080). I had to do a factory reset to get port 80 functionality back.